# Excel VBA stops without error message

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that stops executing for no apparent reason and without generating an error. Could it be a memory problem? The sheet it is operating on has about 1600 rows with lots of formatting and conditional formatting, and the code stops after inserting a row. Here is the code snippet where it stops:

```
With wsBudget
    TotalColumn = .Range("TotalColumn").Column
    FormulaColumn = .Range("FormulaColumn").Column

    If .Cells(lRow, 1).Interior.Color <> 14408946 Then  'OK to insert
        cell.EntireRow.Copy
        cell.Resize(RowCount, 1).EntireRow.Insert  'It stops after stepping into this line
        .Cells(cell.Row - RowCount, 1).EntireRow.ClearContents
        .Cells(cell.Row - RowCount - 1, FormulaColumn).Resize(RowCount + 1, 1).FillDown
        .Cells(cell.Row - RowCount - 1, TotalColumn).Resize(RowCount + 1, 1).FillDown
        .Cells(cell.Row - RowCount - 1, 1).Resize(RowCount, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'OK to insert or delete
    Else
        MsgBox "You must select a cell within a table before inserting a row."
        Exit Sub
    End If

End With
```

Comment: investigate how the `Exit Sub` works, what it does and when it occurs in your code. I recommend stepping through the Debug process

Comment: You need to include error handlers to code. If you have used `On error resume next` then remove it.
'Instead use `On error goto err_location:` and route it to a label. With `Err` object you can examine the issue.

Comment: also, and I'm not sure if it's on purpose but, the reference for the line that stops and the one before that aren't qualified.  Should be a . (dot) in front of the cell keyword (notice the case difference).

Comment: @mehow: It doesn't reach the Exit Sub line. There is a comment in my code on the line where it stops executing: it is the ....entirerow.insert line.

Comment: @Santosh: As I said in the question, it is not generating an error so error handling doesn't help me. I know it is not generating an error because I have indeed tried on error goto.

Comment: @sous2817: Sorry I didn't include the full code. It was in fact deliberate, cell is declared as a Range variable and the code above is within a For Each Cell in .... construct.

Comment: Do you have events in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with entirerow.insert. The problem only appeard with my first execution after I had edited my code or comment lines (without changing any meaningful). My original workbook was a .xltm file but saving it as regular .xlsm solved the problem for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I think I might have an answer (or at least a workaround). As I indicated above, I thought it might be related to the clipboard. So immediately before the copy instruction, I inserted

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

and the problem has now gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I am 90% sure this is a bug in Excel.  I have had the issue on multiple macros, and it is inconsistent even when all other factors are constant; a re-run usually just works.  It is also more likely on a long running macro.

It is not the `Exit Sub` because that follows a message box.  It is not the lack of error handling because VBA should break (and does) if there is an unhandled error.  An error is also reproducible.

The best work around I have found is to output the start and end times on the "Main" worksheet.  If the user does not get an end time, then the macro is assumed to have halted prematurely.